# jQuery no longer setting checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Previously the code I had working in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/swp8kvhw/2/) set the appropriate textboxes based on the "select all" checkbox in their respective tables. After pushing this to the office git server and over to the validation server, it no longer works. Looking at the console, there are no errors popping up and the jQuery does appear to execute as it should.

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
function CheckboxClick(checkbox)
{
    var $name = $(checkbox).attr('name');
    if ($name.indexOf("ChannelPublish_") > 0 || $name.indexOf("hkDisplay_") > 0)
    {
        var $row = $(checkbox).closest("tr");
        if ($name.indexOf("ChannelPublish_") > 0)
        {
            SetDataBin($row, "txtPublishMessage_");
        }
        else if ($name.indexOf("hkDisplay_") > 0)
        {
            SetDataBin($row, "txtDisplay_");
        }
    }
    else if ($name == "chkRemoveAllNetworks")
    {
        $('td input:checkbox', '#tblNetworks').prop('checked', $(checkbox).checked);
    }
    else if ($name == "chkRemoveAllChannels")
    {
        $('td input:checkbox[name*="chkChannelRemove"]', '#tblChannels').prop("checked", $(checkbox).checked);
    }
}
```

Both the select all checkboxes have `onclick='CheckboxClick(this)'`.

Comment: Could you give us an example of this problem? *"Committing this code to our git server and now it's not working"* isn't much to go on.

Comment: Is the example link actual? It does give me the error `ReferenceError: CheckboxClick is not defined    {"error": "Please use POST request"}` when I click the first checkbox..

Comment: Using the JSFiddle linked in the question, if you select one of the "Remove All" checkboxes, it **should** select/unselect them all. However, despite the code executing the appropriate line it doesn't. I'm trying to verify that I'm not completely crazy and the solution is something blindingly obvious and I'm just missing it.

Comment: your fiddle is not referencing jquery

Comment: @Kenney The JSFiddle is the actual code, I don't get those errors on the console when debugging.

Comment: @Sushil [I fixed it](http://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/swp8kvhw/2/)...I'm not sure how I pulled that off.

Comment: Still doesn't work in my FF, even with jQuery. (that 'Please use POST request' is quite strange)

Comment: @Kenney There in lies the problem. Syntax wise, it -looks- correct, and I pulled the html directly from the source.

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/swp8kvhw/3/

Comment: @Trasiva does it work for u?

Comment: you need to replace `$(checkbox).checked` with `$(checkbox).is(':checked')`

Comment: @Sushil Give me a moment, I'm going to test it on the test server.

Comment: @Sushil Beautiful, it works! Toss that up as the answer for your rep. I'll have to look into why `is(':checked')` worked versus `.checked`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84613/discussion-between-sushil-and-trasiva).

Comment: let me post that as an answer

Comment: It's [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/swp8kvhw/4/). You used `$(checkbox).checked` as a value instead of `$(checkbox).prop('checked')`. To fix the function not defined error I set the code to run without wrap in <body>.

Comment: @Kenney Too slow by a few seconds, Sushil just discovered the same thing. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: If I didn't have to clean up after breaking a glass I would've been in time ;-) You're welcome, it was an interesting problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to replace `$(checkbox).checked` with `$(checkbox).is(':checked')` for it to work. and instead of adding `onclick` directly in the html, I added it in jquery. so your checkbox click events should look like this

```
$('input[name="chkRemoveAllNetworks"], input[name="chkRemoveAllChannels"]').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this));
    CheckboxClick($(this));
});
```

you can also replace the `click` with `change` and it will work too

```
$('input[name="chkRemoveAllNetworks"], input[name="chkRemoveAllChannels"]').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this));
    CheckboxClick($(this));
});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/swp8kvhw/3/)**